# JavaScript - string versus integer key

Tags: javascript, performance, benchmarking

I was running performance benchmarks for jQuery (don't ask) and discovered something interesting. For some reason it seems that `this[0] = element` is quite slow compared to `this.foo = element`. Here is the obligatory [jsPerf case](http://jsperf.com/string-integer-property).

Can anybody explain why there is such a performance hit? Is there any way to improve the performance apart from the obvious "use a string key"?

Comment: could you give us a sense of the difference in performance? (ie, 30% slower vs 100x slower)

Comment: Some other test http://jsperf.com/test-string-and-index . I guess the performance hit has to do something with array.

Comment: Speed is irrelevant if you're using a property that doesn't qualify as a valid identifier. In those cases, you need to use `[]` irrespective of performance differences.

Comment: Also, be sure to test in your actual environment instead of just jsPerf. I don't trust it.

Comment: Property that doesn't qualify as valid identifier will cause very bad performance hit on Chrome. Fun thing is there is almost no difference on IE.

Answer (score 2):

The `[0]` has to be found to be incompatible, cast to a string (`"0"`), and then used as a string lookup `["0"]`.

I don't know that it explains 100% of what's going on, but that's the universal part, anyway.
Most of the rest would be under-the-hood optimizations, on a per-engine basis.

This is also not an array, nor an array-lookup.
It's just bracket-notation on an object.

Comment: But on an array `[0]` is faster than `['0']`: http://jsperf.com/string-integer-property/5.

Comment: That's because it's an array. Arrays use integers and objects use strings.